# Why Rolling back is not working when I altered the value of 'sort_buffer_size' in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, internals, mysqladministrator

I changed the value of system variable 'sort_buffer_size' inside a transaction
block. After issuing rollback, it is not getting reverted. Please see the below
snapshot:
[please see the below snip regarding what I did in my local machine MySQL 5.7

server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvOuR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Because these statements do not change any data, only the configuration of the mysql server, therefore they are not part of the transaction. This is the normal behaviour.

As mysql documentation on [SET statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-variable.html) says:

> If you change a session system variable, the value remains in effect
>   within your session until you change the variable to a different value
>   or the session ends. The change has no effect on other sessions.
>
> If you change a global system variable, the value is remembered and
>   used for new sessions until you change the variable to a different
>   value or the server exits.

Comment: Thank youu soo much for your timely response